# Dividing the blob in Emgu CV

Tags: c#, image-processing, blob, emgucv

I am using Emgu CV 2.4.2 and want to perform the following algorithm:

1. **Get the blob**
2. **Set the ROI to speed up computation**
3. **Get the pixel position of local minima from the blob**
4. **Dividing the blob**
5. **Draw the bounding rectangle into divided blob**

I have done step 1-2 and extracted the blob by using BGStatModel. This is the result I've got :

[Blob Picture](http://chardavid.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/newbox.jpg)

I want to get the pixel position of the local minima in vertical projection. After getting it, I want to divide the blob and draw the rectangle like this :

[vertical projection Picture](http://chardavid.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/vertical-projection.jpg)

I have tried to get get the pixel position of local minima by checking every pixel in the blob area but it makes my application runs very slow. Here's my code :

```
Point minPix = new Point(0,0);

//copy the foreground frame
Image<Gray, Byte> foreFrame_copy = foreFrame.Copy();

//find the contour
Contour<Point> contours = foreFrame.FindContours(
    CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
    RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL);

//looping every contour
while (contours != null)
{
    double PPixel = contours.Area;
    if (PPixel >= 1400)
    {
        //get the contour width
        WR = contours.BoundingRectangle.Width;
        //divide the contour using estimated pixel position
        Num = Convert.ToInt32(WR / 40);

    if (Num > 1)
    {
        //save the estimated pixel position for ROI in arraylist
        ArrayList XList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 1; i <= Num; i++)
        {
            int x = i * WR / Num;
            XList.Add(x);
        }

        //get the estimated pixel position 
        foreach (int pos in Xlist)
        {
            //roiWidth= 10px
            int roiWidth = (pos-5) + (pos+5);
            //roiHeight= 20px
            int roiHeight = 20;

            int pixValue = 0;
            //STEP 2: set the ROI to speed up computation
            foreFrame_copy.ROI = new Rectangle(contours.BoundingRectangle.X, contours.BoundingRectangle.Y, roiWidth, roiHeight);
            for (int i = (pos-5); i < roiWidth; i++)
            {
                for (int j = (pos-5); j < (pos+5); j++)
                {
                    pixValue = foreFrame_copy.Data[i, j, 0];
                    //find the white pixel
                    if (pixValue == 255) {
                        //find the position of minimum pixel
                        if (j < j-1) {
                        minPix.X = i;
                        minPix.Y = j;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
    //draw the red rectangle
    estimatedFrame.Draw(contours.BoundingRectangle, new Bgr(Color.Red), 1);
    contours = contours.HNext;
}
else
{
    contours = contours.HNext;
}
}
//show frame in framebox
blobBox.Image = foreFrame_copy;
estimatedBox.Image = estimatedFrame;
```

**Please help me how can I do step 2-5 in fastest way using Emgu CV. I would be highly appreciate if someone elaborate these three steps and some code also.**

Thanks in advance,
David

Comment: From your figure, it looks like the "extreme points" are simply the leftmost, rightmost, uppermost and bottommost points. This is easily done in linear time. You probably mean something else by "extreme points" which is different from my earlier observation and is also unrelated to regional extrema. Can you clarify this step ?

Comment: You are doing steps 1 and 2 the correct way. I don't understand what you mean as "extreme points", from the picture you show these points are simply obtained using vertical projections and finding local minima on it. If you want some help on it, let us know.

Comment: Hi mmgp and Luca, thanks for the reply. I've edited the title to make the problem clearly. What I mean about the extreme minimum point is the local minima on that vertical projection. You can see from this picture  (the green circle). I have tried to get it by checking every pixel, but the result is very slow. Could you provide me the faster way in emgu cv? Thanks in advance, David

Comment: Not clear yet, for me. I'm looking at your "local minimum pixel Picture" and it doesn't fully make sense yet. How was the leftmost image obtained ? How is the vertical projection in the middle figure obtained ? There are many ways to convert the left figure to a function, and I don't see how this is made clear in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply mmgp. To make it clear, maybe you can read page 34 (Step 2) of this [paper](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7xXWz7pAO2OWVhHcUZyeE9vLW8) first. I found a problem to apply Vertical Projection Algorithm (Figure 4d - Figure 4e) in my application. Could you show me how to apply it in EmguCV ? If it isn't clear yet, let me know mmgp :). Thank you in advance, David

Comment: I'm sorry but that paper is badly written. It seems there is some form of threshold based on the width of the blob to estimate how many people are in the blob (which is bound to fail for a vertical group of people). I didn't bother to further decrypt their vertical projection algorithm, here is the result of a simple one that I can produce: http://i.imgur.com/nKPKD.png. Does this output resemble anything you get ? Now, from this output, it is clear that there must be some way to ignore some minima and, in this case, only consider one minima (because there are only 2 people).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the question becomes more clear right now. Personally I agree with mmgp user in that the paper you are taking as a reference is not so good due to lack of generality. It has been coded for a very particular scenario and with some strong assumption on the controlled environment.

I provide you with a method that compute vertical and horizontal projection and absolute maxima points as a good starting point

```
   private void ComputeProjections(Image<Bgr, byte> inputImage)
    {                        
        Image<Gray, Byte> inputGrayImage = inputImage.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
        Matrix<float> imgMatHorizontal = new Matrix<float>(inputGrayImage.Height, 1, 1);
        Matrix<float> imgMatVertical = new Matrix<float>(1, inputGrayImage.Width, 1);

        inputGrayImage.Reduce<float>(imgMatHorizontal, REDUCE_DIMENSION.SINGLE_COL, REDUCE_TYPE.CV_REDUCE_AVG);
        inputGrayImage.Reduce<float>(imgMatVertical, REDUCE_DIMENSION.SINGLE_ROW, REDUCE_TYPE.CV_REDUCE_AVG);
        double minH, maxH, minV, maxV;
        Point minLocH, maxLocH, minLocV, maxLocV;
        imgMatHorizontal.MinMax(out minH, out maxH, out minLocH, out maxLocH);
        imgMatVertical.MinMax(out minV, out maxV, out minLocV, out maxLocV);

        Image<Gray, Byte> maskProvaH = new Image<Gray, byte>(new Size((int)(maxH - minH + 1), imgMatHorizontal.Rows));
        Image<Gray, Byte> maskProvaV = new Image<Gray, byte>(new Size(imgMatVertical.Cols, (int)(maxV - minV + 1)));

        for (int i = 0; i < imgMatHorizontal.Rows; i++)
            maskProvaH.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF((float)(imgMatHorizontal[i, 0] - minH), i), 1f), new Gray(255), 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < imgMatVertical.Cols; i++)
            maskProvaV.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(i, (float)(imgMatVertical[0, i] - minV)), 1f), new Gray(255), 1);

        inputImage.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(minLocV.X, minLocH.Y), 2), new Bgr(Color.Green), 1);
        //imageBoxProjected.Image = inputGrayImage;
        imageBoxHorizProj.Image = maskProvaH;
        //imageBoxVerticProj.Image = maskProvaV;

    }
```

If you are interested in finding local maxima as in the referenced paper you could start implementing a simple local maxima search such as ( code for horizontal projection) :

```
List<Point> localMaxima = new List<Point>();
        imgMatHorizontal.MinMax(out minH, out maxH, out minLocH, out maxLocH);

        Image<Gray, Byte> maskProvaH = new Image<Gray, byte>(new Size((int)(maxH - minH + 1), imgMatHorizontal.Rows));
        for (int i = 0; i < imgMatHorizontal.Rows; i++)
            maskProvaH.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF((float)(imgMatHorizontal[i, 0] - minH), i), 1f), new Gray(255), 1);

        //// Absolute Horizontal Projection Maxima Drawing
        //inputGrayImage.Draw(new Cross2DF(new PointF(maxLocH.X, maxLocH.Y), 2, 2), new Gray(255), 2);

        // Local maximas search
        for (int i = imgMatHorizontal.Rows - 2; i > 1; i--)
        {
            float prev = imgMatHorizontal[i + 1, 0];
            float curr = imgMatHorizontal[i, 0];
            float next = imgMatHorizontal[i - 1, 0];
            if (curr >= prev && curr >= next)
                localMaxima.Add(new Point((int)curr, i));
        }
```

This code comes from one of my youtube demos:

[Facial Features Demo using projections](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibjxxrLKcbY)

The rest of the steps are quite trivial and you can adjust it to your needs or follow some cross ratio thresholds as suggested in the paper.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your local maxima search function, it will also yield all plateau points except those on the border of the plateau, even if the plateau as a whole is not a local maxima. Is that intended ? An efficient way to find the regional maxima/minima is using a proper implementation of the morphological reconstruction.

Comment: As I stated the local maxima/minima search it's only a starting point in developing more complex efficient methods as the one you are suggesting. Taking a look at the paper when two people overlap it's possible to have plateau points and then to define the proper boundary I think it's necessary to impose some conditions using the distance between the first human head and the second (i.e. between to local maxima).

Comment: @mmgp : I've implemented Luca's method in my system and it's working. Thank you very much for helping me guys :)